# wget recursive/mirror option not following links

Tags: shell, wget

I am trying to mirror a website at the moment. `wget` seems to do the job very well, however it's not working on some pages.

Looking at the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Advanced-Usage.html), the command

```
wget -r https://www.gnu.org/
```

should download the GNU page. And it actually does that. However, if I use another page, for example the startpage of my personal website, this doesn't work anymore.

```
wget -r https://my-personal.website
```

The `index.html` is downloaded, but none of the CSS/JS not to mention the recursive download. All that is downloaded is the `index.html`.

I've tried setting the User-Agent using the `-U` option, but that didn't help either. **Is there an option missing that is causing wget to stop after the `index.html`?**

UPDATE: I've also tried the `--mirror` option, which is also not working and showing the same behavior.

Comment: Can you try with "-m,  --mirror             shortcut for -N -r -l inf --no-remove-listing."

Comment: @bdn02 Already tried that, it's not working either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your website uses a relatively less-known form of robots control, through the `<meta>` tag in HTML. You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag). Wget will correctly adhere to the instructions in this robots directive. You can see this happening, if you look a little closely at the debug output of Wget when trying to recursively download the website:

> no-follow in my-personal.website/index.html: 1

Now, unfortunately, that's not a very helpful message unless you're one of the developers and know the codebase. I will try and update the message to be something a little more clear in this case. Just the way we do when such things happen due to a `robots.txt` file.

Anyways, the fix is simple, disable robots parsing. While this is okay when accessing your own website, please be mindful about the web servers when doing this to others. The full command you need is:

```
$ wget -r -erobots=off https://my-personal.website
```

EDIT: As promised, added an improved message. See [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/commit/?id=e39be3283836b8cb7b9ee320456eefb2a2fda173). It now prints:

> no-follow attribute found in my-personal.website/index.html. Will not follow any links on this page

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution! That was a fast patch, nice to see that :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this only works if there is no whitespace between `-e` and `robots`. I'm not sure if this is official, [but I found this first](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html#How_can_I_make_Wget_ignore_the_robots.txt_file.2Fno-follow_attribute.3F), and it has a space between them, and it definitely didn't download all the files I expected. I ran it again without the space and now it is working as expected.